# How to use Rating bar in sencha touch or phonegap?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, ratingbar

I want to use a Rating Bar for Phonegap and sencha in android. For the i referred with the below links:

[sencha-touch-2-ux touch rating](http://podlipensky.com/2012/03/sencha-touch-2-ext-ux-touch-rating/)

So i kept **Ext.ux.touch.Rating.js** and **Ext.ux.touch.Rating.css** in the **www** folder inside **assets**. In **app.js** i added the below line:

```
requires : ['Ext.ux.touch.Rating'],
```

And in js file, i added the below code:

```
xtype : 'rating',
                label : 'Star Rating',
                itemsCount : 5,
                itemCls : 'x-rating-star',
                itemHoverCls : 'x-rating-star-hover',
                clearIcon : true
```

But it is giving me error below in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not getting where i have to keep those files and use them.

Answer (score 0):

try using it directly in Sencha Touch. That should work